MSK Topics Backup and Restore using AWS Firehose
I am working on a Disaster recovery of MSK where I use AWS Firehose to stream data directly into S3 bucket from MSK cluster and it is very straight forward. I could see raw data in S3 whenever new data is being pushed in MSK cluster, so the backup process is all fine. Here no serialization is used, so the raw data is being uploaded in S3.
Facing issue while restoring the same back to MSK cluster from S3 bucket. Here I am using MSK S3 connector from lenses to restore the topics. I don't see any issues/errors in restoration logs but all I could see is only values in topics and not keys and headers. I am kind of confused here as not sure whether the restoration is incorrect or the raw data in S3 does not have keys and headers coz somewhere in AWS re-post a question was raised about headers.

Could you expect a raw file individually for what it contains? According to docs, the restore function is expecting data in a format by the corresponding sink, not Firehose - https://docs.lenses.io/5.3/connectors/sources/s3sourceconnector/#backup-and-restore
